# How do I fix the error about a widget being unmounted so the State no longer has a context in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I get an error. Here is the debug console:

```
════════ Exception caught by scheduler library ═════════════════════════════════
This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I am using the [`flutter_riverpod`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod) package. I'm using it for a search field and when searching for something it shows this error. Also, search doesn't work. Here is some code:

User interface code:

```
TextFormField(
  …
  onChanged: (search) => controller.updateSearch(search),
  onSaved: (search) {
    search == null ? null : controller.updateSearch(search);
  },
),
```

---

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
 if (mounted) {
    return name.contains(state.search) ? ListTile(title: Text(name)) : Container();
  }

  return Container();
},
```

Controller code:

```
class Controller extends StateNotifier<State> {
Controller() : super(State());

void updateSearch(String search) => state = state.copyWith(search: search);

}

final controllerProvider = StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose< Controller, State>((ref) {
  return Controller();
});
```

State code:

```
class State {
  State({this.search = "", this.value = const AsyncValue.data(null)});

  final String search;
  final AsyncValue<void> value;
  bool get isLoading => value.isLoading;

  State copyWith({String? search, AsyncValue<void>? value}) {
    return State(search: search ?? this.search, value: value ?? this.value);
  }
}
```

Feel free to comment if you need more information!

How to fix this error? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's ok, thanks for taking the time to read the question

Comment: Can you try with autoDisposed and checking if the state is mounted

Comment: Hi @YeasinSheikh I don't quite understand what you are talking about. Can you answer this question and share the code?

Comment: While create riverpod provider, you can find `StateProider.autoDispose` . not sure it will work, next is checking the state is disposed or not ,then perform action. Can you provide a sample full widget with provider that will reproduce the same error

Comment: @YeasinSheikh do you mean `controller` should be `StateProider.autoDispose`?

Comment: yes, just a guess

Comment: @YeasinSheikh my `controller` is now using `StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose`

Comment: Sorry cant say .

Comment: @YeasinSheikh It's okay, thank you for taking the time to reply to me

Answer (score -1):

Try with below code snippet.

```
if (mounted) {
  setState(() {
   // To do 
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Is "..." a widget?

Comment: Do not forget to upvote. if it really helps you.

Comment: I never tried it, do you mean return the widget in the `if` function?

Comment: I saw your edit and tried it. However, the error remains…