# How to create a search field in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, search, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I am using the [`flutter_riverpod`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod) package. I'm using it for a search field and it's showing an error when searching for something. I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74316651/16124033) about the error but couldn't fix it. Is there any other way to create a search field in Flutter using the [`flutter_riverpod`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod) package?

Here is some code:

User interface code:

```
TextFormField(
  …
  onChanged: (search) => controller.updateSearch(search),
  onSaved: (search) {
    search == null ? null : controller.updateSearch(search);
  },
),
```

---

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
 if (mounted) {
    return name.contains(state.search) ? ListTile(title: Text(name)) : Container();
  }

  return Container();
},
```

Controller code:

```
class Controller extends StateNotifier<State> {
Controller() : super(State());

void updateSearch(String search) => state = state.copyWith(search: search);

}

final controllerProvider = StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose< Controller, State>((ref) {
  return Controller();
});
```

State code:

```
class State {
  State({this.search = "", this.value = const AsyncValue.data(null)});

  final String search;
  final AsyncValue<void> value;
  bool get isLoading => value.isLoading;

  State copyWith({String? search, AsyncValue<void>? value}) {
    return State(search: search ?? this.search, value: value ?? this.value);
  }
}
```

Is there something wrong with the code above? If yes, what is the way to create the seach field using the [`flutter_riverpod`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod) package? If not, why am I getting the error message (go to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74316651/16124033) to see the error message)?

If I can't create a search field using the [`flutter_riverpod`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod) package in Flutter, how can I create a search field (I hope maybe without using any package and without using `setState` function)?

Feel free to comment if you need more information!

How to fix this error? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Update:

We can discuss in [this room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249359/create-a-search-field-in-flutter).

Comment: You can check [this out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wm3OiFBZ2xI&t=2585s&ab_channel=GoogleDevelopers). it may help you. It is what I use together with StateNotifierProvider as a controller.

Comment: Hi @john thanks for your comment. Can you explain what that YouTube video is about? If you know how to do it, can you answer this question and share how to do it?

Comment: the video is all about creating a search field using the `SearchDelagate` class. Do you really need that State class? because for me, if that's the only content then i dont think it's necessary because I can just simply do this `StateNotifier<AsyncValue<void>>` to track the loading state.

Comment: Hi @john I don't know how to write the code can you answer this question and share the code?

Comment: Hi @pskink Thanks for your comment. Does the code have to use the `flutter_bloc` package?

Comment: @pskink There is also something wrong with your code. [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MN7le.png) shows that the search field is too high, although I used the `Padding` widget, it didn't go lower

Comment: the first sample does not use bloc, also you need to add `SaveArea`

Comment: @pskink What do you mean by "the first sample"? Which widget should I wrap with a `SafeArea` widget?

Comment: `FooSearch` - the first sample

Comment: @pskink sorry, I still don't understand can you answer the question and paste the code?

Comment: use `FooSearch` widget and not `FooLocalBlocSearch`

Comment: @pskink I see it. Can I use the [`flutter_riverpod`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod) package to do this?

Comment: sure, use `StreamProvider` for example, https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/StreamProvider-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
class FooSearchRiverpod extends ConsumerWidget {
  final controller = StreamController<String>();
  late final provider = obtainProvider(controller);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    AsyncValue<List<String>> list = ref.watch(provider);
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          onChanged: controller.add,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search), hintText: 'search...'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: list.when(
            loading: () => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            error: (err, stack) => Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                child: Card(elevation: 4, child: Text(err.toString())),
              ),
            ),
            data: (list) => AnimatedSwitcher(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: list.length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ListTile(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  title: Text(list[i]),
                  onTap: () => debugPrint('onTtap: ${list[i]}'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  obtainProvider(StreamController<String> controller) {
    return StreamProvider.autoDispose<List<String>>((ref) => controller.stream
           .debounce(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000))
           .asyncMap(_getAPI));
  }

  final list = ['foo', 'foo 2', 'bar', 'bar 2', 'spam'];
  Future<List<String>> _getAPI(String query) async {
    debugPrint('_getAPI: |$query|');
    if (query.isEmpty) return [];
    return list.where((s) => s.contains(query)).toList();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this may not answer directly the question but it may give another variation on how to restructure the code.
To track the loading state, from the controller:

```html
class Controller extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<void>> {
Controller({required this.repository}) : super(AsyncData(null));

//this depends on where your search api is located at.
//for this example i use repository because it is mostly where its is.
final SeachRepository repository
 
Future<void> submitSearch(String search) async {
state = const AsyncLoading();
 //`.guard` is used to handle possible errors from your API so no need 
  // to use `try/catch`
state = await AsyncValue.guard(()=> repository.submitSearch(search));
}

}

final controllerProvider = StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose< Controller, AsyncValue<void>>((ref) {
  return Controller();
});
```

You can use your controller from your UI like this:

```html
final controller = ref.watch(controllerProvider.notifier);

TextFormField(
  …
  onChanged: (search) => ref.read(searchValueProvider.notifier).state = search,
  onSaved: (search) {
    search == null ? null : controller.submitSearch(search);
  },
),
```

And for the loading state:

```html
//your loading state
final state = ref.watch(controllerProvider);

//to handle passible error:
ref.listen<AsyncValue>(controllerProvider, (_, state)=> showAlertDialog(context));


itemBuilder: (context, index) {
 if (mounted) {
    return name.contains(state.search) ? ListTile(title: Text(name)) : Container();
  }

  return state.isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Container();
},
```

for the search variable, you can store it in a StateProvider for easy access:
final searchValueProvider = StateProvider.autodispose((ref)=> '');

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, can you share the code of `SeachRepository`?

Comment: There is a problem with using this, `state` is not a `State` class, so I can't use `state.search`. How to solve this problem?

Comment: actually i removed the State class. you can convert your search string into StateProvider like so `final searchValue = StateProvider<String>((ref)=>'');`

Comment: So, how to do it?

Comment: i included in my answer

Comment: Same problem in UI code, `state` is not a `State` class, so I can't use `state.search`.

Comment: so you are trying to access the `search` from the state i defined? no, you cant. the state is just for loading, data and error. if you want to access the seach, access it from the stateProvider: `final search = ref.watch(searchValue.state).state;`